# Use C# to check is string contains an integer in a given range of numbers

Tags: c#, string, search

I have a list of strings, some of which fall in the format "LAP1_...", "LAP2_...", ... , "LAP9_...". I want to count all the strings that follow the format "LAP" plus any integer 1-9. Is there a way to check if a string contains a substring that includes any integer in a given range?

I could obviously write the code like this:

```
 var lapCount = recentRecords.Where(x => x.nkFileName.Contains("LAP1")||x.nkFileName.Contains("LAP2") || x.nkFileName.Contains("LAP3")
            || x.nkFileName.Contains("LAP4") || x.nkFileName.Contains("LAP5") || x.nkFileName.Contains("LAP6") || x.nkFileName.Contains("LAP7")
            || x.nkFileName.Contains("LAP8") || x.nkFileName.Contains("LAP9")).Count();
```

but that seems unnecessarily long.

I would rather have the search look something like this:

```
 var lapCount = recentRecords.Where(x => x.nkFileName.Contains("LAP[1-9]")).Count();
```

Comment: you're actually almost [there](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/dotnet/standard/base-types/regular-expressions)

Comment: How about `... Regex.IsMatch(x.nkFileName, "LAP[1-9]")` ?

Comment: I changed my code to: ```var lapCount = recentRecords.Where(x => Regex.IsMatch(x.nkFileName, "LAP[1-9]")).Count();``` but I now get the following error: "LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'Boolean IsMatch(System.String, System.String)' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression."

Comment: It would be important to tell us you are using LINQ to Entity Framework, and then what EF you are using: EF 6.x / EF Core 2.0 / EF Core 2.1 / EF Core 3.x? `recentRecords` obviously isn't a `List<string>` given that error.

Answer (score 0):

You could use char.IsDigit
https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/dotnet/api/system.char.isdigit?view=netcore-3.1

string stringWithNumber = "sample 43 string 7 with number 42";
stringWithNumber.Any(char.IsDigit);

Answer (score 0):

Reverse the test so it can be translated:

```
var lapCount = recentRecords.Where(r => r.nkFileName.StartsWith("LAP") && "0123456789".Contains(r.nkFileName.Substring(3,1))).Count();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following code snippet:

```
   List<string> strList = new List<string>()
    {
            "LAP1","ABC","explorer","LAP2","LAP3","xyz"
    };
    var myRegex=new Regex(@"LAP[0-9]");
    List<string> resultList=strList.Where(f => myRegex.IsMatch(f)).ToList();
```

The result would be:

[image: Result]

So In your case, I believe you can use:

```
var myRegex=new Regex(@"LAP[0-9]");   
List<string> resultList=recentRecords.Where(f => myRegex.IsMatch(f.nkFileName)).ToList();
```

Make sure that `recentRecords` is a list of strings.